# Is there any widget for iframing a link/url and make it viewable on homescreen in full or resizable area?

Tags: applications, app-widgets

Is there any widget for iframing a link/url and make it view able on home screen in full or re sizable area?

Answer (score 5):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

- [Meta Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.metawidget): `Create widgets from almost any website element`
- [Websnap-Web capture,Web widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.web2mine.wg01): `take a snapshot of any web page or part of a page and display it on your Android home screen with a refresh interval of your choice`

Feel free to search Google Play for related apps.

Comment: Thanks. But I also need some images to be displayed as well, like thumbnails, in that case the above widget wont be that useful.

Comment: @jitendra Hard to imagine what you are really looking for. What sample website do you want to view on a widget?

Comment: I want to view my personalized edition of google news. I mean I have to sign in. The closest is WebSnap, however, I cannot click on the link (headlines). it is just like a viewable newspaper.

Comment: Is there any up to date app like these? Both of them dated to 2016 and never updated, both have very low ratings

Answer (score 0):

As geffchang has suggested, there are some widgets that can show a thumbnail/screenshot of the website, but it's not possible to have a fully working, interactive view like you get in a web browser.

Home screen widgets don't run like normal apps: instead, the *widget provider* tells the home screen app what *layout* the widget should have, from a set list of GUI elements (text, buttons, images, &c.). It's not possible to include a web browser view in that layout.